# calling route via jquery or action="" confusion

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a problem which I am not understanding properly. Let me try to explain. When i call a route by`href="{{route=('name_of_route')}}"` it actually works. When I call the same route by `jQuery on sumbit` it works too but it behaves differently. Some code fragments are not being executed like `dd();` (not in the code now) and the `compact` part of `return view('CV_Test.excel',compact('like_values'));`. The variable is not being passed to the view. The Database part and passing the request to the controller all is fine. Can someone explain why? Here is my code. I tried to make the 2 examples. I hope it is ok now I am asking my question. Thanks in advance.

**View example 1**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <center>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>xlsx, xls, ods, csv to Text</h3>
            <form  id="xlsForm"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <input type="file" name="excelfile" />
                <input id="excelSubmit" type="submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </center>
    <div class ="row">
        <div class ="col-md-3">
            <div class="container mt-5">
                <h2 id="words" class="mb-4">Skills found</h2>
            </div>
            @if(isset($like_values))
                <form id="xlsFormUpdate"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    @foreach($like_values as $values)
                        <input type="checkbox" id="skillChoice" name="skills" checked>
                        <label for="skillChoice">{{$values}}</label><br>
                    @endforeach
                    <input id="skillSubmit" type="submit"/>
                </form>
            @endif
        </div>
        <div class ="col-md-9">
            @include('layouts.partials.datatable')
        </div>
    </div>   
@endsection
```

**JS belongs to example 1**

```
$('#xlsForm').submit(function uploadFile(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{route('ExcelToArray')}}",
        method: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        dataType: 'JSON',
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        complete: function () {
            load_data()
        },
    });
});
```

**View example 2 without Jquery**

```
extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <center>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>xlsx, xls, ods, csv to Text</h3>
            <form href={{route('ExcelToArray')}} method ="post" id="xlsForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <input type="file" name="excelfile" />
                <input id="excelSubmit" type="submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </center>
    <div class ="row">
        <div class ="col-md-3">
            <div class="container mt-5">
                <h2 id="words" class="mb-4">Skills found</h2>
            </div>
            @if(isset($like_values))
                <form id="xlsFormUpdate"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    @foreach($like_values as $values)
                        <input type="checkbox" id="skillChoice" name="skills" checked>
                        <label for="skillChoice">{{$values}}</label><br>
                    @endforeach
                    <input id="skillSubmit" type="submit"/>
                </form>
            @endif
        </div>
        <div class ="col-md-9">
            @include('layouts.partials.datatable')
        </div>
    </div>   
@endsection
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('/excel', [ExcelController::class , 'ExcelToArray'])->name('ExcelToArray');
```

**Controller**

```
public function ExcelToArray (Request $excelFile) {
    $excelFile->validate([    
        'excelfile' => 'required|mimes:xlsx,xls,csv,html,ods',
    ]);
    $excelimport = new ExcelImport();

    Excel::import($excelimport, $excelFile->file('excelfile'));
    $clean_text = $excelimport->clean_text;
    $like_values = $this->get_matched_words_as_array($clean_text);
    DB::table('results')->truncate();

    foreach ($like_values as $key => $like_value) {
        $out = DB::Table('employees')->where('skills', 'like', '%' . $like_value . '%')->get();
        foreach ($out as $out_value) {
            $hit = $this->check_frequency($like_value,$out_value->skills);
            DB::Table('results')->insert([
                'skills' => $out_value->skills,
                'team' => $out_value->team,
                'email' => $out_value->email,
                'first_name' => $out_value->first_name,
                'last_name' =>$out_value->last_name,
                'hit' => $hit,
                'word' => $like_value,
            ]);
        }
    }
    return view('CV_Test.excel',compact('like_values'));
}
```

Comment: Is the javascript in a js file or in your blade? Look at the source in your browser and make sure the URL is being printed correctly.

Comment: Hi @aynber. It's in my blade. Like i said it is calling the route. I am pretty sure the source is ok.

Comment: Check what parameters & values are actually getting send in each instance, you can easily do that by inspecting the request in your browser dev tools, network panel.

Comment: What does `load_data()` do?

Comment: Hi @CBroe, ok ill take a close look. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: dd() will not work, because you need to include it. On ajax laravel will not provide errors or dump data by default.

Comment: Hi @shaedrich load_data() gets data from a database and passes it to a yajra datatable. The controller in this question inserts the datasets into the results table and load_data() loads them from the results table to my yajra datatable. That is working. The query to get the data is in another controller.

Comment: @Bapi, i know i wrote in brackets in my question that it is not in my code now. Trust me i tried. If i include the dd(); the code after dd(); will not be executed this is why i just mentioned it without writing it down.

Comment: I think it might be related to the fact that i am giving the datatype as JSON and i am expecting now the variable to be passed to render the html. The approach is wrong. Btw i have no clue why i am getting downvoted like this. However thanks for your efforts.  I will have to stick to google to find a way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

So the Problem was related to the fact that calling a route via jquery requires the response from the controller to be handled by the **"success"** part of  **Ajax**. The controller has to send the data in json format to the view. In order to render the html in the desired way i had to use the **.prepend** method to manipulate my html. Here is my code in case someone is interested.

**JS**

```
    $('#xlsForm').submit(function uploadFile(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('ExcelToArray')}}",
            method: "POST",
            data: new FormData(this),
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function (response) //<<<<<<<<added part begin
            {

               $("#inner").empty();
                $.each(response,function(index,value){
                    $("#inner").prepend('<input type="checkbox" id="skillChoice" name="skills"  checked>    <label for="skillChoice">'+value+'</label><br> ');
                });
            },                                //<<<<<<<<added part end
            complete:function ()
            {
                load_data()
            },
        });
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
     public function ExcelToArray (Request $excelFile)

{
     $excelFile->validate([

        'excelfile' => 'required|mimes:xlsx,xls,csv,html,ods',

         ]);

    $excelimport = new ExcelImport();
    Excel::import($excelimport, $excelFile->file('excelfile'));
    $clean_text = $excelimport->clean_text; // Anforderung
    $like_values = $this->get_matched_words_as_array($clean_text); // Wörter die in Anfoderngsdokument gefunden wurden.
    DB::table('results')->truncate();
    //dd($like_values);

    foreach ($like_values as $key => $like_value) {

        $out = DB::Table('employees')->where('skills', 'like', '%' . $like_value . '%')->get();

        foreach ($out as $out_value)
        {
            $hit = $this->check_frequency($like_value,$out_value->skills);
            DB::Table('results')->insert([
                'skills' => $out_value->skills,
                'team' => $out_value->team,
                'email' => $out_value->email,
                'first_name' => $out_value->first_name,
                'last_name' =>$out_value->last_name,
                'hit' => $hit,
                'word' => $like_value,
            ]);

        }


    }

    return response()->json($like_values); //<<<<<< changed part 


    }
```

**BLADE**

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')

    <center>
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>xlsx, xls, ods, csv to Text</h3>
        <form id="xlsForm"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <input type="file" name="excelfile" />
            <input id="excelSubmit" type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    </center>

    <div class ="row">
        <div class ="col-md-3">
            <div class="container mt-5">
                <h2 id="words" class="mb-4">Skills found</h2>
            </div>
                <form id="xlsFormUpdate"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf

                    <div id="inner">   <!--div to manipulate-->
                    </div>

                    <input id="skillSubmit" type="submit"/>
                </form>

        </div>
    <div class ="col-md-9">
    @include('layouts.partials.datatable')
    </div>

    </div>


@endsection
```