# laravel ajax unexpected end of json input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Hello guys i am desperate i am not getting completly this syntax / concept of Ajax.

I have 2 forms on my page. Based on the value of the hidden field a certain logic in my controller will be executed. Its simple actually -- i thought. I am trying to pass an array from my ajax to my controller and then passing it back to my view. I know it doesnt make much sense. But i am trying to understand how that works. The first logic gets executed but the other one gets me this error:
*jqXHR is : [object Object] textStatus is : parsererror errorThrown is : SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input*

Why is that ? Can you guys please give me an advice.

**Update**

I tried not to put the whole code and just reduce it to the main question. But since it caused confusion of the rootcause i will show the whole code of the parts which might be relevant. I edited the question to the below.

**BLADE**

```
 <center>
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>xlsx, xls, ods, csv to Text</h3>
        <form id="xlsForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <input type="file" name="excelfile" />
            <input name ="loadSubmit" id="loadSubmit" type="submit"/>
            <input type ="hidden" name="load" value="0">
        </form>
    </div>
    </center>

    <div class ="row">
        <div class ="col-md-3">
            <div class="container mt-5">
                <h2 id="words" class="mb-4">Skills found</h2>
            </div>
                <form id="xlsFormUpdate"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type ="hidden" name="load" value="1">
                    <div id="inner">
                    </div>
          <input name ="updateSubmit" id="updateSubmit" type="submit"/>
                </form>

        </div>
    <div class ="col-md-9">
    @include('layouts.partials.datatable')
    </div>

    </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
  if ($request->input('load') == '0') {

         //some code -- this works fine 

return response()->json($data);  //This data can be send - no problem


     } elseif (($request->input('load') == '1')) {

      $data = $request->post('checkbox_array'); 
 
         return response->json($data); // i tried json_encode too .. not working.

     }
```

**Jquery code**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#xlsForm').submit(function uploadFile(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('ExcelToArray')}}",
            method: 'POST',
            data: new FormData(this),
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function (response) {
               $("#inner").empty();
                $.each(response,function(index,value){
                    $("#inner").append
                    ('<div class="row">' +
                        '<div class="col-xs-2">'+
                        '<input type="checkbox" class="'+value+'" value="'+value+'" name="checkbox[]"  checked >  <label style="font-weight: bold" for="skillChoice_'+index+'">'+value+' </label>' +
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div class="col-xs-1">'+
                        '<input class="'+value+'" type="number" name="weight[]" min="1" max="3" value="1"> '+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>');
                });
            }
          
        });
    });


    $('#xlsFormUpdate').submit(function uploadFile(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var checkbox_array = [];

        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function (index,value) {

            if (this.checked)
            {
                checkbox_array.push(1);
            }
            else {
                checkbox_array.push(0);
 
            }
        });
           
        let checkbox_s = JSON.stringify(checkbox_array)

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('ExcelToArray')}}",
            method: "POST",
            data: {checkbox_array:checkbox_s},
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,

            success: function (response) {
                alert('The Response is ' + response);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('jqXHR is : ' + jqXHR
                    + 'textStatus is : ' + textStatus
                    + ' errorThrown is : ' + errorThrown);

            },
              

        })
    });          





    });
```

Comment: No `$_POST(['checkbox_array']);` is not the right way to access POST data. But this is not a problem with AJAX but with your understanding of PHP syntax. `$_POST` is an array variable and these are accessed via bracket syntax like so: `$_POST['checkbox_array']`. Parentheses are mostly for functions or conditions.
https://www.php.net/manual/de/langref.php

Comment: You can only pass scalar types from one language to another, not compound types. Compound types need to be serialized (often times stringified) in order to be properly transmitted. Therefore you need either `response()->json($compoundValue);` or `response(json_encode($compoundValue));`

Comment: Hi @shaedrich what is the way to access this particular data? i know for example to access input i write `$request->input('name')` or file `request->file('name)` but here i dont know.

Comment: You should be able to do either `$request->checkbox_array;`, `$request->post('checkbox_array');` or `$request->input('checkbox_array');` to access the value.

Comment: please change this line " return response($data);" to return response()->json($data), moreover you are looping over a non existent element "input[type=checkbox]"

Comment: Hi @shaedrich, i tried both and updated the question based on your comments. I didn't change. Same error.

Comment: @Emeka Okafor, thanks for your answer, tried that too. Not working. Even if i dont send any data to controller but just want to send a simple string as a a response it gives me same error. I am really despreate. Maybe the whole approach with the 2 forms is causing error? Idk :(

Comment: If you open your browser's DevTools and go to the network panel what's the response value?

Comment: @shaedrich It says "This request has no response data available". No matter what i take as response. A simple string like `return response()->json($string_variable);` Same. Its logic, its running into this error i am facing.

Comment: What is the output if you `dd($request->all());`?

Comment: @shaedrich `dd();` won't execute calling a route by ajax. See my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68179307/calling-route-via-jquery-or-action-confusion However when calling the route by `action="{{route('name_of_route')}}"` then `dd();` will be executed and if gives me all submitted values but not like i want. i need everything handled by ajax because i need that array in that way. Otherwise i will not get the unchecked checkboxes. Regardless of this point. What is the cause of this Problem :(

Comment: No further ideas?

Comment: I know what the problem is. Ill answer the quesiton soon.

Answer (score 0):

When using ajax submit event to send data to controller, the data in the field `data: {checkbox_array:checkbox_s},` will be send to the controller. Since the input field `load` was never sent, the `elseif (($request->input('load') == '1'))` clause was never true and the controller was never going into that section and was never returning the right response. The data had to be changed like this  `var my_datas JSON.stringify({mydata:checkbox_array, load: "1"});` and then in ajax the data could be send like `data:my_datas`. In controller the field `load` can then be processed.